# Lagging data based on condition (non-fix lag)

Tags: r, conditional-statements, lag

I have data ordered in chronological ascending order. These are currency pairs associated to prices. I need to create a new "MtM" column that will be equal to price when currency pair is XAU/USD. However, whenever the currency pair is different from XAU/USD, then MtM needs to be equal to the last previous price in which currency pair was equal to XAU/USD.

I have tried lagging, cusum, mutate but I am able to solve only the case when there is only one observation in which currency is different from XAU/USD. If there is more than one consecutive line when currency is different from XAU/USD, I am not able to solve.

```
Currency <- c("XAU/USD", "XAU/USD", "XAU/GBP","XAU/USD","XAU/EUR","XAU/GBP","XAU/USD")
Price <- c(1297, 1296, 1007, 1295, 1005,1004,1298)
df <- data.frame(Currency, Price)
```

I need to get

```
MtM <- c(1297, 1296, 1296, 1295, 1295,1295,1298)
df <- data.frame(Currency, Price, MtM)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way using `dplyr` and `tidyr` -

```
df %>% 
  mutate(
    MtM = ifelse(Currency == "XAU/USD", Price, NA_real_)
  ) %>% 
  fill(MtM)

  Currency Price  MtM
1  XAU/USD  1297 1297
2  XAU/USD  1296 1296
3  XAU/GBP  1007 1296
4  XAU/USD  1295 1295
5  XAU/EUR  1005 1295
6  XAU/GBP  1004 1295
7  XAU/USD  1298 1298
```

Answer (score 2):

An option with `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(MtM = case_when(Currency == "XAU/USD" ~ Price, TRUE ~ NA_real_)) %>% 
  fill(MtM)
#  Currency Price  MtM
#1  XAU/USD  1297 1297
#2  XAU/USD  1296 1296
#3  XAU/GBP  1007 1296
#4  XAU/USD  1295 1295
#5  XAU/EUR  1005 1295
#6  XAU/GBP  1004 1295
#7  XAU/USD  1298 1298
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, here is also a `data.table` solution which uses the `nafill()` function (new with [development version 1.12.3 of `data.table`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md):

```
library(data.table) # version 1.12.3+
setDT(df)[Currency == "XAU/USD", MtM := Price][, MtM := nafill(MtM, "locf")]
df
```

> ```
>    Currency Price  MtM
> 1:  XAU/USD  1297 1297
> 2:  XAU/USD  1296 1296
> 3:  XAU/GBP  1007 1296
> 4:  XAU/USD  1295 1295
> 5:  XAU/EUR  1005 1295
> 6:  XAU/GBP  1004 1295
> 7:  XAU/USD  1298 1298
> ```

The `:=` operator indicates *to update by reference*, i.e., without copying the whole object. This can be a speed advantage for large datasets.

For `data.table` *prior* to version 1.12.3, `na.locf()` from the `zoo` package an be used:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[Currency == "XAU/USD", MtM := Price][, MtM := zoo::na.locf(MtM, na.rm = FALSE)]
```

Comment: The last line can be writte `setDT(df)[Currency == "XAU/USD", MtM := Price][, MtM := zoo::na.locf0(MtM)]`